Firebase Google analytics doesn't work in jetpack compose
I carefully did all the tutorial said, like 5 times already, and nothing works.
there's no any data in my firebase console, and yes i'm sure its this project.
Here is all i did:

Installed all dependencies

build.gradle.kts Project level
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("com.google.gms:google-services:4.4.2")
    }
}

// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
plugins {
    id("com.android.application") version "8.7.3" apply false
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.android") version "1.9.24" apply false
    id("com.google.gms.google-services") version "4.4.2" apply false
    application
    kotlin("plugin.serialization") version "1.9.0"
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.9.0"
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.plugin.compose") version "2.0.0" apply false
}

build.gradle.kts Module level

download google-services.json from guide to my project, added it in "app" directory, change nothing in it.
here's the file

created private lateinit var firebaseAnalytics: FirebaseAnalytics
3.1) Initialize it firebaseAnalytics = Firebase.analytics
3.2) Log open event firebaseAnalytics.logEvent(FirebaseAnalytics.Event.APP_OPEN, null)
Installed app and nothing in realtime analytics. i was starting and reinstalling the app many days 'cause i have seen that it needs like 48 hours to start. Nothing.

Tried to run it on release mode - Nothing

Tried to make another project in jetpack compose (didn't try views)

Created new project in firebase

Install firebase and check if it works (i dont use it) and it worked.

I have another app with another project, and in this project its actually works but i did this like a year ago so i dont know how, i tried copying all from this project partially, no effect

Im living in russia, does it mean i cant use google analytics? i think no, i searched the net and it says no so i think there is no problem here.


If it helps here is my settings.gradle.kts
pluginManagement {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        gradlePluginPortal()
    }
}

dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

rootProject.name = "CollegeS"
include(":app")

